# When a union object is copied, is a member subobject created?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions, memcpy, object-lifetime

When another member of a union is accessed, the C++ standard used to be silent on what happens, but that was fixed to explain that member access to a union object was allowed for the purpose of assigning to that yet no existent object, which would magically create the object, by assignment to it or one of its members. Essentially the member access operator returns a promise of a future object and you have to use it with an assignment.

Given

```
union U {
  int i;
  long l;
};
```

We can create a `i` or `l` member subobject by assignment:

```
U u;
u.i = 2; // creates an int
u.l = 3; // creates a long (destroys the int)
```

But what happens when the union object is copied? How would the compiler "know" which member to "create"?

```
U u1, u2;
fill(&u1);
u2 = u1; // which u2 member is created here?
```

When using `memcpy` on a union from a buffer of bytes filled with numerical values (not filled from another union object), which member becomes "active"?

```
char buf[sizeof(U)] = { ... };
U u;
memcpy(&u, buf, sizeof u);
```

Comment: The compiler does not know. The programmer must write correct code!

Comment: I think the standard is not explicit about this, but I suppose the intention is that copying a union also sets the same member active (if any). The last case would then probably not set any member active. In any case the compiler does not need to know this, because there is no behavior dependent on the active member that isn't UB.

Comment: @Phil1970 When is code correct? What are the exact requirements?

Comment: In my experience the whole `union` value is copied whether all of the bits are currently used or not. Can't find anything specific in the Standard though.

Comment: @user4581301 [The implicit copy assignment is defined to copy the object representation of the union](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/special#class.copy.assign-13) and [that is defined to contain all bits](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#types-4). But I don't think that implies any object creation or setting of active members per se.

Comment: @walnut that completes [In simple assignment (=), the object referred to by the left operand is modified (`[defns.access]`) by replacing its value with the result of the right operand.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#2) Thanks for digging that up.

Comment: Side note for those playing along at home, if the members are NOT trivial, [things get ugly](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.union#4).

Comment: @user4581301 The definitions in [expr] define only the behavior of the built-in operators for the most part. Since `union` is a class type its overloaded operators are described in [class.special].

Comment: @walnut Is copying object representation the same as copying "underlying bytes"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't know. "*underlying bytes*" is only used twice without a direct definition of the term, but a reference to [intro.memory] that I would have understood as equivalent to "*object representation*", which is defined explicitly directly after the uses of the term "*underlying bytes*". I don't know what the intended difference between the two is supposed to be.

Comment: @walnut If it is the same, then, at least for trivially copyable unions, we can say which object becomes active after assignment.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer As far as I can tell the paragraphs about copying of "*underlying bytes*" only specify what happens to the value of (sub)objects that already exist, but doesn't include the creation of a subobject necessary to set the active member. But I really don't know for sure whether I am reading it correctly or not. I guess the intention for defaulted union assignment to set the active member is clear though, even if not spelled out.

Comment: @walnut I don't understand how can a union object `obj1` have **the same** value as union object `obj2` and yet doesn't have the same member active.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think you may be right. Again, I am not confident that my previous assertions are true, which is why I didn't write an answer. The only thing I wanted to say is that a wording explicitly mentioning the active member after copying is lacking. My second comment might have been worded too strongly in that regard.

Comment: @walnut I'm also not 100% sure that "object representation" and "underlying bytes" are the same, even for trivially copyable types. But there is feel that this is the same thing. And if so, it is clear which member is active after the assignment.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Postulating that a member is "active" is one thing, starting its lifetime is another.

Comment: @curiousguy How is it possible? Active == refers to a subobject within lifetime.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It is *not* possible, that's my point. It's inconsistent. You can pretend (based on the std text) that a member is active; but then, its lifetime must have started at a some point in the execution. There must be **a thing in the C++ program that is known to be able to create an object.** What is that thing? I don't see it. Many times ppl on SO have told me that `malloc(sizeof(int))` does not create an `int` because `malloc` isn't listed as a thing that creates objects, so presumably ppl treat that list of things seriously. (OTOH I never cared about these things before.)

Comment: @curiousguy Ok, I see. Hope P0593 will solve this.